# SSRS where-clause with value that contains an @

Tags: reporting-services, dataset

In SSRS 2005 we have a query in a dataset and the query filters on a certain value which happens to contain an @. Eg: select * from test where testfield = '@LC'. SSRS thinks this value should be a parameter and treats it that way. How can configure my query so that SSRS treats it as a fixed value? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already tried with '[@]LC'

Comment: Replace your statement with
 select * from test where testfield LIKE '@LC'
and try it out.

Comment: it's OK, i did a workaround with hidden parameters etc. Thanks anyway!